# Why I can't plot a 3D plot correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So i am trying to plot 3rd col and my axes will be first two column;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5csnh.png)

Now i run this code in python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = np.array([
    [1, 0, 14.69064283],
    [0.2, 0.8, 10.83751709],
    [0.4, 0.6, 11.80079853],
    [0.6, 0.4, 12.76407996],
    [0.8, 0.2, 13.7273614],
    [0, 1, 9.87423566],
    [0, 0.8, 10.94980008],
    [0, 0.6, 12.0253645],
    [0, 0.4, 13.10092892],
    [0, 0.2, 14.17649334],
    [0, 0, 15.25205776],
    [0.2, 0, 15.13977477]
])

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
z = data[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_title('Values plotted against [x, y, z]')

plt.show()
```

but the result showing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/725t0.png)

where notice, these no point visible againt [1,0] (for example); i tried online plotting website and on Math3d:Online i plotted the same data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuFlK.png)

Where i am doing wrong??

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If you rotate your plot to a top view you will see that you have all the points. However in the code you posted you are using `cmap='viridis'`  but the picture you posted don't correspond to this colormap (the top points should be yellowish instead of blueish). Are you sure the picture you posted corresponds to this code?